# SQL Server: How use 'case when' in query?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, case-when

I try `case when` with `null` and `not null` set to value `ErrorCode` field.

**Ex.**

```
EmpNo|ChkDate                |ChkIn                  |ChkOut                 |ErrorCode
00001|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 07:21:00.000|2012-10-01 17:05:00.000|0
00002|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 22:17:00.000|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|6
00003|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 19:30:00.000|6
00004|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|NULL                   |NULL                   |7
00005|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 07:10:00.000|2012-10-01 12:00:00.000|0
00006|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 13:50:00.000|2012-10-01 19:20:00.000|0
```

**But i need Output (ErrorCode)**

```
EmpNo|ChkDate                |ChkIn                  |ChkOut                 |ErrorCode
00001|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 07:21:00.000|2012-10-01 17:05:00.000|0
00002|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 22:17:00.000|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|6
00003|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 19:30:00.000|6
00004|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|NULL                   |NULL                   |7
00005|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 07:10:00.000|2012-10-01 12:00:00.000|8
00006|2012-10-01 00:00:00.000|2012-10-01 13:50:00.000|2012-10-01 19:20:00.000|8
```

**valued in ChkIn and ChkOut is Half Day. I need set value = 8. but i try = 0.**

**This Code:**

```
SELECT
   tf.EmpNo, tf.ChkDate, tf.ChkIn, tf.ChkOut,
   CASE
      WHEN ChkIn is not null and Convert(nvarchar(10), ChkOut,108) != '00:00:00'
         THEN 0
      WHEN ChkIn is not null and Convert(nvarchar(10) ,ChkOut,108) = '00:00:00'
         THEN 6
      WHEN Convert(nvarchar(10),ChkIn,108) = '00:00:00' and ChkOut is not null
         THEN 6
      WHEN Convert(nvarchar(10),ChkOut,108) <= '12:00:00'
         OR Convert(nvarchar(10),ChkOut,108) >= '12:00:01' Then 8
      WHEN ChkIn is null and ChkOut is null THEN 7 
   END as 'ErrorCode'
FROM filesTA tf
WHERE tf.ChkDate = '2012-10-01'
```

Comment: Why does EmpNo 1 get code 0, but EmpNo 5 and 6 get 8? How are you defining full day, and half day? You won't be able to differentiate between those without some kind of elapsed time calculation, and I can't tell from your existing query what the logic should be. Please explain more clearly when the values 0, 6, 7, and 8 should be applied to a row.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your conditions "overlap". By that I mean that an early condition applies (in your case: the first one), and a later condition would also apply, but the `case` statement ends on the first match.

What you need to do is to rephrase your conditions so they identify each case uniquely.

Your first condition says `ChkIn` should not be `null` and `ChkOut` should be not equal to `00:00:00`. While this condition is also true for the lines where you expect the result to be `8`, the first "match" is applied by the `case` statement.

**EDIT**
I do, however, not quite understand your requirement as to when the output is expected to be `0` and when it is expected to be `8`. Maybe you could explain a little further the exact conditions when which value should be returned. I'm having trouble understanding *valued in ChkIn and ChkOut is Half Day. I need set value = 8.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide conditions that will not falsely return true earlier in your case statement. You could try the following that moves the calculation for 8 earlier:

```
SELECT
   tf.EmpNo, tf.ChkDate, tf.ChkIn, tf.ChkOut,
   CASE
      WHEN Convert(nvarchar(10),ChkOut,108) <= '12:00:00'
         OR Convert(nvarchar(10),ChkOut,108) >= '12:00:01' Then 8
      WHEN ChkIn is not null and Convert(nvarchar(10), ChkOut,108) != '00:00:00'
         THEN 0
      WHEN ChkIn is not null and Convert(nvarchar(10) ,ChkOut,108) = '00:00:00'
         THEN 6
      WHEN Convert(nvarchar(10),ChkIn,108) = '00:00:00' and ChkOut is not null
         THEN 6
      WHEN ChkIn is null and ChkOut is null THEN 7 
   END as 'ErrorCode'
FROM filesTA tf
WHERE tf.ChkDate = '2012-10-01'
```

But this will just make 0 never appear. The fact is that your desire is not clear. Why does EmpNo 1 get code 0, but EmpNo 5 and 6 get 8? How are you defining full day, and half day? You won't be able to differentiate between those without some kind of elapsed time calculation, and I can't tell from your existing query what the logic should be. Please explain more clearly when the values 0, 6, 7, and 8 should be applied to a row.

Comment: *I* know that. *You* know that. But he doesn't. Thus an example for him to really see the nature of the problem.